# How to clear file type input field's file name in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, input

in this **input field**, it will only accept video files.
if I try to upload any other files, by  enabling all files option. it will show a alert.
that's working fine but after adding any other format file, when it checking that it is not a video file, it showing the alert but file name is remaining in the input field.

I want to clear the input field file name and `e.target.files` as clear.
this is my code...

```
<Label for="exampleFile">Upload Video</Label>
      <MyInput
        type="file"
        name="file"
        accept="video/*"
        id="exampleFile"
        label="Upload a Video"
        onChange={(e) => {
          let files = e.target.files;

          let file = files[0];
          let name = files[0].name;
          let type = files[0].type;

          if (!file.type.match("video.*")) {
            alert("You Can't upload a video file ");
          } else {
            // some code
          }
        }}
      />
```

[image]

**when I am uploading any other format, it showing the alert, After clicking the `OK` button.it is showing....**

[image]

the file name is still in the input field. I have to **reset** it.

I have tried with...

> 1. `document.getElementById('exampleFile').value = null`
> 2. `useRef()`
> 3. added a `value` property with `useState()`
>    but nothing is working.

**can anyone help me to solve this issue...**

Comment: Why are you using `MyInput` instead of a simple `input` tag? You may experience problems using another component instead of a simple HTML input when trying to use the same methods on it.

Comment: it is a custom component only,

Comment: I guess the id `exampleFile` is not working on the input field which is what you want, but it is only a property on your custom component. What's the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting a key attribute to the file input, then when you  needed to reset it update the key attribute value:

```
  resetsFileInput() {
      let randomString = Math.random().toString(36);
     setInputKey(randomString)
     
    }

       <Label for="exampleFile">Upload Video</Label>
       <MyInput
        type="file"
        key={InputKey || '' } />
        name="file"
        accept="video/*"
        id="exampleFile"
        label="Upload a Video"
        onChange={(e) => {
          let files = e.target.files;

          let file = files[0];
          let name = files[0].name;
          let type = files[0].type;

          if (!file.type.match("video.*")) {
            alert("You Can't upload a video file ");
          } else {
              resetsFileInput()

            // some code
          }
        }}
      />
```